# How to Connect a Router to a WiFi Source in DD-WRT

Tags: openwrt, dd-wrt

Portable travel routers like the D-Link DIR-510L have the ability to connect to other routers wirelessly as their source and provide a separate wireless network.

This is advantageous when traveling from location to location, as only the DIR-510L needs to be connected, and all devices on your persons continue to auto-connect to the wireless network provided by the 510L. No duplicate entries of new wireless passwords on 6 or 7 devices that you are traveling with. This also segregates the discoverability between media devices on your personal traveling network and allows VPN setup for traveling media devices. Some locations also do not provide physical access their routers.

Is there any way to imitate this handy functionality in DD-WRT or OpenWRT? It would be unfortunate for such a small/simple router to have this functionality and it not be possible on a high performance router with DD-WRT or OpenWRT installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that [this ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/391918) outlines how this can be achieved by connecting the router as a client and then creating a sub-interface to broadcast a different SSID.

Comment: I do this at home using the dd-wrt Client Bridge instructions, but I'm not sure this meets OP's portability needs. There may be some relevant info, though. https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Bridged